Java decompiler - Which JD (or JD-Eclipse) version did generate line-numbered source code?
I did have a folder containing lots of Java source code which I believe many of them (thousands) were decompiled from jar files using Java Decompiler tool (https://java-decompiler.github.io/) as they contain the comment at the bottom of the files:
enter image description here
I don't think they are manually exported due to the number of files and now I have some jar files which I want to re-export with the same format (i.e having line-numbered starting each line and the bottom comment).  However, I still can't find the way to do that on the web.
Have you ever done such a thing? Could you help with that?
Any helps are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Luke P
Below are what I tried, but not work as expected.

Try installing JD-Eclipse but it can show only each .class file, no way to export classes for the whole jar
Try installing Enhanced Class Decompiler add on in Eclipse. It does allow to export the whole jar (into a zip file) but not with the comment as I expect.


https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-core JD-core, has a Save All feature to export all the decompiled source files from a jar file.

(Just FYI, there's also a fork of jd-core, https://github.com/nbauma109/jd-gui-duo, which allows other decompilers, too. The most modern one with the most correct code, I think, is Vineflower (https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower), which also provides a CLI to export all files from a jar. With difficult/obfuscated jars, sometimes you need multiple decompilers and some manual touches to get everything in the right shape.)

Thanks a bunch Petr. "Save All" is exactly what I need.
